# Increasing a thumbs "click area" in UISlider

Tags: iphone, ios, uislider

I am creating a custom UISlider and wonder, how do you increase a thumb image's "click area" ? The code below works great, except the thumb's "click area" remains unchanged. If I am not wrong, I believe the standard thumb area is 19 px ? Lets say I would like to increase it to 35px with the following code below, what steps do I need to take? Keep in mind I am not an expert within this area at all.

**EDIT** *The code below is corrected and ready for copy pasta! Hope it helps you!*

**main.h**

```
#import "MyUISlider.h"

@interface main : MLUIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, MLSearchTaskDelegate, MLDeactivateDelegate, MLReceiptDelegate>
{
  ..........

}

- (void)create_Custom_UISlider;
```

**main.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[self create_Custom_UISlider];
[self.view addSubview: customSlider];

}

- (void)create_Custom_UISlider
{
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 320.0, 280, 0.0);


customSlider = [[MyUISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

[customSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
// in case the parent view draws with a custom color or gradient, use a transparent color

customSlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_slider08.png"]
           stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_slider08.png"]
            stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 260.0 topCapHeight:0.0];


[customSlider setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_button00"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customSlider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customSlider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];


                    customSlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
                    customSlider.maximumValue = 1.0;
                    customSlider.continuous = NO;
                    customSlider.value = 0.00;

}

-(void) sliderAction: (UISlider *) sender{

if(sender.value !=1.0){
 [sender setValue: 0.00 animated: YES];
}
else{
[sender setValue 0.00 animated: YES];
 // add some code here depending on what you want to do!
  }
}
```

**EDIT** (trying to subclass with the code below)

**MyUISlider.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyUISlider : UISlider {

}

@end
```

**MyUISlider.m**

```
#import "MyUISlider.h"

@implementation MyUISlider



- (CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value
{


return CGRectInset ([super thumbRectForBounds:bounds trackRect:rect value:value], 10 , 10);

}


@end
```

Comment: See my working example to the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26316371/258931

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom UISlider - Increase "hot spot" size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196263/custom-uislider-increase-hot-spot-size)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to **override** `thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:` in a custom **subclass** (instead of *calling* the method yourself like you do in your code, which does nothing except returning a value that you don't even bother to retrieve).

`thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:` is not a method to *set* the tumb rect, but to *get* it. The slider will internally call this `thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:` method to know where to draw the thumb image, so you need to override it — as explained in the documentation — to return the `CGRect` you want (so that it will be 35x35px as you wish).

Comment: Ive tried different approaches but failed. Probably because I am bad and doing something wrong. Ive edited my code above, could you please show (fill in or fix the code) and show how you would have done it? If not, thx for your help. You have at least pointed me in the right direction....

Comment: You have the right code structure. All you need is to implement the method to return the correct `CGRect` according to the `trackRect` and `value` (as the thumb is at a different position depending on the slider value of course), as explained in the doc. Just some simple math to do. And of course write `customSlider = [[MyUISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];` in your `create_Custom_UISlider` method, to instanciate a `MyUISlider` and not a standard `UISlider`.

Comment: Thanx for you answer Ali. I forgot to change the code to the MyUISlider alloc.. But what I don't understand is how I should structure the code in the method: - (CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value
{
 ?????? 
} to return something useful that works. I understand you can not give me exact numbers, but what would you put in this method if you look at the rest of my code? Thanx once more for your help!

Comment: Why not simply rely on the `super` implementation, and simply return `CGRectInset([super thumbRectForBounds:bounds trackRect:rect value:value], -10, -10)` to have a rectangle 10x10 larger than the one used by the `UISlider` superclass for example?

Comment: I did what you said and tried other things aswell. I am still not able to make it work. I have edited/updated the code above so you can see what I tried last time. I have also made some screens to demonstrate what it looks like currently with the latest code and before I subclassed it here: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=347dufa&s=5

Comment: There seems to be an error in the implementation of `thumbRectForBounds...`. There is no `return` statement before the `CGRectInset` call. You should have:

`return CGRectInset ([super thumbRectForBounds:bounds trackRect:rect value:value], -10 , -10);`

Answer (score 13):

**Updated for Swift 3.0 and iOS 10**

```
private func generateHandleImage(with color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.height + 20, height: self.bounds.size.height + 20)

    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: rect.size).image { (imageContext) in
        imageContext.cgContext.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        imageContext.cgContext.fill(rect.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10))
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
self.sliderView.setThumbImage(self.generateHandleImage(with: .white), for: .normal)
```

**Original answer:**

By far the easiest method is just to increase the size of the thumb image with invisible border around it:

```
- (UIImage *)generateHandleImageWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.height + 20.f, self.bounds.size.height + 20.f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectInset(rect, 10.f, 10.f));

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

And than adding this image to slider:

```
[self.sliderView setThumbImage:[self generateHandleImageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: this answer (in Swift) only generated and placed the image for me.  It did not change the "click area" for the thumb for me...

Comment: For me, this has the thumb not be aligned with the left edge of the UISlider when the value is the minimumValue.  Because the UISlider adjusts the minimumValue position for the size of the thumbImage.  Any solution for that issue?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and solved it by overriding

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

method.
You can return YES for those points, that you want to be touched.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my double slider [project](https://github.com/raphaeloliveira/DoubleRangeSlider)

In summary, I implemented the **hit test method** so the **beginTrackingWithTouch** is invoked.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.leftHandler.frame, point) || CGRectContainsPoint(self.rightHandler.frame, point)) {
        return self;
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Check the [class](https://github.com/raphaeloliveira/DoubleRangeSlider/blob/master/DoubleRangeSlider/DoubleRangeSlider.m) for further details

Answer (score -1):

why you wanna go for custom slider while you can change the area of a default slider ;)

take a look at this code it worked for me to increase the touch area of my UISlider hope it helps you too

```
CGRect sliderFrame = yourSlider.frame;
sliderFrame.size.height = 70.0;
[yourSlider setFrame:sliderFrame];
```

Comment: You could make the slider 1000 high but the thumb. would still be the same size.