# UISlider with increased slider size but no thumb distortion in iOS App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I need to increase size of slider in the `iOS app` created using `Xamarin Forms`. I tried with following custom renderer that overrides **`LayoutSubviews`**.  It increases the size but there is an unacceptable size increase for the thumb. How to reduce the size of the thumb keeping the increased height of the slider?

It is possible in Android as shown here:  [Increase height of slider without affecting thumb in Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45602266/increase-height-of-slider-without-affecting-thumb)

**iOS References:**

1. [Custom UISlider - Increase "hot spot" size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196263/custom-uislider-increase-hot-spot-size/26316371#26316371)
2. [Increasing a thumbs "click area" in UISlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177398/increasing-a-thumbs-click-area-in-uislider)

**C# Custom Renderer**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MySlider), typeof(MySliderRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.iOS
{
    class MySliderRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.SliderRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Slider> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);   
            Control.MinimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0xE6, 0x00, 0x06);
            Control.ThumbTintColor = UIColor.Red;
            Control.MinimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.Orange;
            Control.MaximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.Yellow;
            //Control.SetThumbImage(UIImage.FromFile("myicon.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(1f, 12.0f);
            transform.TransformSize(this.Frame.Size);
            this.Control.Transform = transform;            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE - REFERENCES - Renderer**

1. [Customizing Control Rendering in Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/videos/cross-platform/xamarinforms-custom-renderers/)
2. [Implementing a View - Rendering a platform-specific view](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/)
3. [iOS range slider for Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms](http://danielhindrikes.se/xamarin/ios-range-slider-for-xamarin-and-xamarin-forms/)
4. [Fullscreen Video Background Control for Xamarin.Forms](https://www.junian.net/2017/03/fullscreen-video-background-control-for-xamarin-forms.html)

Answer (score 6):

Override `TrackRectForBounds` to change its height  instead of changing `transform` .

**In MySliderRenderer**

```
class MySliderRenderer : SliderRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Slider> e)
    {
        SetNativeControl(new MySlideriOS());
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }
}
```

**Create a subclass of UISlider**

```
public class MySlideriOS : UISlider
{
    public MySlideriOS() {
        this.MinimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0xE6, 0x00, 0x06);
        this.ThumbTintColor = UIColor.Red;
        this.MinimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.Orange;
        this.MaximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.Yellow;
    }

    public override CGRect TrackRectForBounds(CGRect forBounds)
    {
        CGRect rect =  base.TrackRectForBounds(forBounds);
        return new CGRect(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, 20);
    }
}
```

**My test**

[image]

Here is [Sample](https://github.com/ColeXm/SliderDemo)

Comment: After making this change, the slider didn't render. I am testing it in Mac. Can you please tell me how you are testing? Also, do you have a working sample project for this?

Comment: @Lijo okay give me some time to prepare，I will provide the link within 8 hours.

Comment: @Lijo are you using vs for mac or windows?

Comment: I am running the project in Windows using VS. It is connected to Mac using Xamarin Mac Agent. And I am verifying the result in Mac.

Comment: @Lijo OK got it.

Comment: Hi brother, did my answer help?@Lijo

Comment: The Mac laptop is not with me now to test it.. Will let you know once I get it..Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Lijo did you figured it out how to increase the bar size? I'm trying Cole Xia code but it's not rendering. any idea?