# Xamarin Form slider customisation for changing the thickness of slider bar in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, slider

Want to customise the ios slider to increase the thickness of slider bar. i tried using scaling but it is scaling the whole slider including the thumbimage and text above slider.

Comment: I found a solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702803/uislider-with-increased-slider-size-but-no-thumb-distortion-in-ios-app/45704597]. but events of slider is not triggering after inheriting UISlider. Can anyone help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to implement this.

1. [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)
2. Create delegate for the custom slider and trigger it in CustomRenderer.

   **Code**:

   *MySlider*

   ```
   public class MySlider : Slider
   {
       public delegate void SlideEventHandler(double newValue);
       public SlideEventHandler SlideEvent;
   }
   ```

   *Page*

   ```
   public Page1 ()
   {
       InitializeComponent ();
       slider.SlideEvent += slideChange;
   }
   void slideChange(double newValue) {
       Debug.WriteLine(newValue);
   }
   ```

   *MySliderRenderer*

   ```
   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Slider> e)
   {
       MySlideriOS slider = new MySlideriOS();
       slider.ValueChanged += Slider_ValueChanged;
       SetNativeControl(slider);

       base.OnElementChanged(e);
   }

   private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MySlideriOS slider = sender as MySlideriOS;
       (Element as MySlider).SlideEvent(slider.Value);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it worked ! :-). Can't upvote because of less reputation.

Comment: @user8671622 Glad it helped you.