# Increase touch target size of UISlider with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I managed to increase the thumb size of my `UISlider` with `Swift` but the touch zone is still too small for my application.

How to programmatically increase the size of the touch zone for a `UISlider`?

Should I re-implement a custom slider by myself?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom UISlider - Increase "hot spot" size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196263/custom-uislider-increase-hot-spot-size)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Subclass `UISlider` and in your custom class of slider add this method,

```
  func pointInside(_ point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    var bounds: CGRect = self.bounds
    bounds = CGRectInset(bounds, -10, -15)
    return CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, point)
}
```

Then create object of that subclass when you used slider.

If you have used slider in `interfacebuilder` (storyboard) then set it's class to that custom slider class from `identity inspector`.

Comment: NIce! It works, but apparently the touch zone stay limited to the thumb size. If the touch zone is bigger than the thumb size, then it's reduced to the thumb size.Thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3** update of Lion's great answer:

```
import UIKit

class CustomSlider: UISlider {

     override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        var bounds: CGRect = self.bounds
        bounds = bounds.insetBy(dx: -10, dy: -15)
        return bounds.contains(point)
     }
}
```